# EnumDropDownListFor not resolving when model is IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to use `Html.EnumDropDownFor(model => model.Gender)`, which works when the model is just `Project.Models.Performer`, but not when it's `IEnumerable<Project.Models.Performer>`.

In Visual Studio I get the following error :

```
"The type arguments for method Html.SelectExtensions.EnumDropDownLostFor<TModel, TEnum>(...) cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the the arguments explicitly"
```

And in browser I get:

```
"CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Project.Models.Performer>' does not contain a definition for 'Gender' and no extension method 'Gender' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Project.Models.Performer>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
```

`Gender` is an enum I've defined in Performer's file.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `EnumDropDownList` and everything to do with your model. You are attempting to bind a `Gender` property to `IEnumerable`.

Comment: `Gender` is an enum I've defined. How do I use it for a drop-down when I need `Performer` to be `IEnumerable`?